# How to hide the select value from the form

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a form which have a select drop down. i have disabled it by default and will re enable it based on some conditions. i don't want anybody to access the select option values when it is disabled(now it can be viewed by inspecting the element from browser). how do i make it secure?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can. You might be better off populating it when it's needed instead of enabling it. You could do that with an Ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`ngIf`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) directive.

> The `ngIf` directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree based on an `{expression}`. If the expression assigned to `ngIf` evaluates to a false value then the element is removed from the DOM, otherwise a clone of the element is reinserted into the DOM.

*Usage*

```
<select ng-if="someCondition"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a simple binding library like knockout.js you can use container-less binding which will only render the select DOM when you want.

Knockout is is a great little library which plays nicely with most other libraries so shouldn't cause any trouble, all you ned to do is import the js file.

Container-less binding will only render the DOM when it needs to, so inspecting the page element will not display the select box.

```
<!--ko if: IsShown -->
    <select>Render Me</select>
<!--/ko-->
```

Here is a simple fiddle to show you how to make it work.

[Knockout Containerless Binding](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/23163/)

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid rendering it, which would hide it from the DOM inspector, but the data would still be in the browser and available to a user who cared to look in the right place.

If you don't want the user to see the data, then don't send it to the client in the first place.

When you want to display the select element, make an Ajax request to the server. Then perform authentication and authorisation to make sure the user is allowed to see the data. Then return it in the response and have Angular generate the select using that data.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to hide part of code from viewing by user in browser, because browsers have to see the code to run it, so it can be viewed by user. But, using php can help you to generate content for page only when it's needed. I think you can generate content for your drop-down, or the whole dropdown using that way.